# TableView not showing refresh data from web Service

Tags: ios4

I have two classes   FirstViewController and SecondViewController.On  FirstViewController i have TableView and UIBarButton named 'Change City' .TableView is showing parsed data from the server. But when i click on Change City ,It  flip  us on SecondViewController.

On SecondViewController we have also a TableView which shows the cities and done button.After selecting the city we pressed Done then SecondViewController again flip to FirstViewController.

i Stored selected city in appDelegate for accessing it on the FirstViewController.

Here Tableview of FirstViewController should have been refreshed but it showing the same data as it was showing earlier.

Please somebody help me to fix this problem.I am doing this from last 2 days.

Comment: How do you refresh your data? It would be great if you can list your `viewWillAppear:`, `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` methods. And before all that, are you doing `[tableView reloadData];`?

Comment: @DeepakDanduprolu. I need some solution. I want to reload / refresh tableview with webservice when I switching one tab to another tab. I am using tabBar application. Can you explain if you have some idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this line- `[tableView reloadData];` to the method that is called when the view controller is set back to FirstViewController, which would be the `viewWillAppear:`/`viewDidAppear:` methods.Hope this helps...